# Column listeners in Extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am trying to figure out what my arguments are on a click event on a **grid column** in Extjs 4.

```
xtype: 'gridpanel',
columns: [{
    header: 'col1',
    dataIndex: 'col1',
    flex: 0.5,
    listeners: {
        click: function () {
            alert('what are my arguments? ' + arguments)
        }
    }
}, {
    header: 'col12',
    dataIndex: 'col2',
    flex: 0.5
}]
```

I know that the arguments look something like this :

[image]

However this is not really helpful due to the 'ducktyping' nature of Javascript. Specifically I want the record, however I can't be 100% sure if I just choose an object that looks like the right thing.

More fundamentally, I am not exactly sure how the API documentation works in Extjs4. If I want to see what arguments are being passed in the click event I would expect to be able to go to the column object (*Ext.grid.column.Column*), and look at its click event. However if I look I cannot find any **click** event.

[image]

Am I understanding something wrong?

Comment: Looks like the docs aren't generated correctly, but you could just expand at indexes 4/5 and see what's there.

Comment: has grid column got the click listener? I can't call a click on column add the listenr like you

Comment: @OliverWatkins Which version of ExtJS exactly are you refering to? At least in higher versions of ExtJS (4.2.2 and above), the `gridcolumn`'s component and `el` are the column header, and the Ext.view.Table then uses the renderer from the column to render the body. So there shouldn't be a `click` event available that is executed on click of a body cell - events for that are on the grid (`cellclick`, `itemclick`) and the grid's selectionmodel. And for clicks on the header, there's the `headerclick` event documented.